# What should I use to connect a rails app with remote servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, websocket, server, vpn

I am using a ruby on rails app which goal is to handle lockers reservations by users and be able to unlock them using a smartphone.

The rails app is hosted on heroku (free plan), and I use several raspberry pi as remote servers that control opening of lockers.

So far, it works with HTTP requests from the app to the raspberry through a free http ngrok tunnel, but this is limited to a few requests per minute, and the connection is not secure/private at all, so it is not really what I need.

What type of solution would you recommend to ensure a more secure connection between the app and remote servers with no request number limitation ? I have a few concepts in mind, but I don't understand them well enough to know what I should look into. VPN ? SSH ? Web sockets ? Should I still use heroku ?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve what you want with all technologies you listed above but I think using web sockets would simplify the setup process and it also seems to be the most robust.

Have a look at this [client](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#using-the-websocket-client) for your Raspberries.

To get the server to work you'll need a [redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) instance, which heroku offers in their free plan so you can keep it there. Your server app will need to use something like ActiveCable or [faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#handling-websocket-connections-in-rack).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I have started to look into websockets. I think I could use ActionCable to set the server side in the rails app.
On the client side, I might have to use a a python client (i used tornado as http server until now), can it connect easily to ws channels set by action cable ?

Comment: I'm sure there is a websockets client library for python.